# Newbie - eclipse workflow (PHP development)

Tags: php, eclipse

this is a bit of a newbie question but hoping I can get some guidance.  I've been playing around with Eclipse for a couple months yet I'm still not completely comfortable with my setup and it seems like every time I install it to a new system I end up with different results.

What I'm hoping to achieve is (I think) fairly standard.

In my environment I'd like SVN (currently using Subclipse), FTP support (currently using Aptana plugin), debugging (going to use XDebug) and all the usual bells and whistles of development (code completion, refactoring, etc.)

My biggest current issue is how to set up my environment to support both a 'development' and 'production' server.  Optimally I would be able to work directly against the dev server (Eclipse on my Vista desktop against the VM Ubuntu dev server) and then push to production server (shared hosting).  I'd prefer to work directly against the dev server (with no local project files, just using the Connections provided by Aptana) but I'm guessing this won't allow for code-completoin or all the other bells and whistles provided for development.  Any thoughts?

Kind of an open ended question, but maybe this could be an opportunity for some of you with a great deal of experience using Eclipse to describe your setups so people like me can get some insight into good ways to get set up.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers - I'm going to switch to NetBeans for now - everything just seems a lot easier with it and subversion, FTP, and auto sync on save are already built in to the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always work with local copy of dev. server environment, so - as you said yourself - I could have full code with auto-completion goodness, but at the same time I am using [FileSync plugin for Eclipse](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/filesync/index.html) which makes things easier - every time I change something - it syncs to the remote dev. server where I can directly do the testing.

That's the dev. part. The deployment to production environment has nothing to do with my Eclipse setup directly. Once I am happy with my current state of project - I commit all things (of course not only then) to CVS (but it not really matters which version control you're using), tag it with some release tag and then use scripts which does the deployment to production machine by given release tag (fetches needed things from CVS by given tag and puts them to production machines).

Comment: Great - it was the syncing I was missing, I tried cwrsync but without much luck.  I'll check out the plugin you referenced.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use Aptana? It's still eclipse based and offers Sync/SVN/FTP/SFTP(SSH)

Answer (score 1):

Aptana does what you are asking, you define a remote and local directory for the files - you can't use a file path as a remote location but you can use a project as one. I have set up a local project and remote project and they sync to each other.